# RewriteRule - section and subsection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect all subsections to the new URL as rewrite rule in .htaccess.

example:

- `example.com/section` => `example.com/new_section`
- `example.com/section/subsection1` => `example.com/new_section`
- `example.com/section/subsection1/subsubsection` => `example.com/new_section`

etc (every section has many subsections and rule form all section/subsection there are hundreds of rules)

I have rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^section[/]?$ /new_section [R=301,L]
```

This redirect only URL `www.example.com/section` to `www.example.com/new_section`, but not redirect `www.example.com/section/subsection1` etc.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^section[/]?$ /new_section [R=301,L]
> ```

The regex `^section[/]?$` only matches `section` or `section/`. You need to match `section/<anything>` as well. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^section($|/) /new_section [R=301,L]
```

NB: Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

> and rule form all section/subsection there are hundreds of rules

Not sure exactly what you mean by this, but the order of rules can be important. Generally, the more specific rules need to go first.